# MS Access gives SQL Server Error "Login Timeout Expired", then connects successfully

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc, windows-authentication

I have a domain with 10+ clients. The server was rebooted recently, and upon reboot, two of the clients are receiving an error when attempting to access the SQL Server. The clients are running Win7 64bit with MS Office 2013 32bit. All the other computers have no issue.

The MS Access database uses linked tables to connect to the SQL Server 2008 R2 using Trusted Authentication. When opening the Access database, Access hangs for about 30 seconds before showing this error message:

*Connection Failed; SQLState: 'S1T00'; SQL Server Error: 0;
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login Timeout Expired*

When I click OK to clear the error, the SQL Login prompt appears. The server address is already entered, and we use a Trusted connection. Without changing any of the settings I click OK to the login prompt, and it connects to the database successfully.

**Sites discussing the same problem** (but without a solution that has worked for me):
[SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1264891-1550-1.aspx) -- [Database Journal](http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?44357-ODBC-connection-Timesout-then-allows-connection)

(I'm limited by reputation and can't post additional links, but I also found a Google Groups post suggesting resetting Winsock. Another post on SQLServerCentral (Topic1245190-391-1) describes the same issue but has no clear solution)

**What I Have Tried:**

1. netsh winsock reset
2. netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
3. netsh int ipv4 reset
4. sfc /scannow
5. Restarting the client computer
6. Run msaccess.exe as administrator
7. Confirm connection strings use server IP, not server name

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need to concurrently collect at least 2 network sniffs (wireshark, netmon, etc.). One sniff should be collected on the Access box and another sniff should be collected on the SQL Server box. A third sniff could be collected on the domain controller, but is not strictly needed. You also need to search support.microsoft.com for known issues, such as the OS fix mentioned in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919863 (which may or may not be applicable to SQL Server's unknown OS version)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem. It's exactly as you posted. Access works locally on the same server as SQL, but on remote machines gave the S1T00 error. The problem was with the firewall. Needed to open port 1433.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is searching for an answer to this down the road, in my case I found that the Client Configuration for the SQL Server driver had somehow been changed to Dynamically determined port. I unchecked that and set the port to 1433 and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers did not work for me.  In the Client Configuration of the ODBC data source, I also found the "Dynamically determine port" was checked / selected and the port number already showed 1433.  But, I was unable to uncheck that option due to requiring Administrative Access to make the change.  Our company has Admin Access locked down.

Deleting and recreating the User DSN (Data Source) resolved it for me.